# RewriteCond expr "true" => not matched

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Here is my mod_rewrite configuration:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond expr "true"
RewriteRule .? - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [QSA,L]
```

And here the relevant logging output:

```
RewriteCond: input='expr' pattern='true' => not-matched
```

The Apache documentation says

> Syntax: RewriteCond TestString CondPattern
>
> If the *TestString* has the special value `expr`, the *CondPattern* will be
>   treated as an [ap_expr](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html).
>
> In the below example, `-strmatch` is used to compare the `REFERER` against
>   the site hostname, to block unwanted hotlinking.
>
> `RewriteCond expr "! %{HTTP_REFERER} -strmatch '*://%{HTTP_HOST}/*'"`
>   `RewriteRule ^/images - [F]`

So if *CondPattern* will be treated as ap_expr and ap_expr can per definition explicitly be `true` then why the hell does the simplest possible expression fitting into that pattern not work? To be exact *no* matching expression works for me. Is anyone out there who can verify that this technique ever worked for anyone?

Because I actually have a pretty complex expression which can not be done with conventional mod_rewrite conditions, it is very important to me to know whether I can use this method anyhow.

EDIT:

For the lazy ones, here the [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) definition of ap_expr directly copied from [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html):

```
expr        ::= "true" | "false"
              | "!" expr
              | expr "&&" expr
              | expr "||" expr
              | "(" expr ")"
              | comp
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using apache 2.4?

Comment: @JonLin Oh my god! You are right, I tried `apache -v` and it gave `2.2.16` to me :O and [the documentation of 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) really does not contain this feature. Thanks, please post your comment as answer so that I can accept it. (I will never understand, why _definitive_ answers are so often postet as comments, since even if this would not have been _my_ solution, it would be another ones! So it is 100%ly _an answer_ .)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're using apache 2.4? The `ap_expr` stuff is all new features that are part of the 2.4 feature set and not a part of 2.2.